# Insert into unordered_map hanging on runtime

Tags: c++, debugging

I've run into an issue that I can only describe as completely unfamiliar to me, and I could use some help. For context, I don't know a whole lot about c++ programming and am trying to learn more, so the code I'm currently working on is more educational than anything else. I want to create an `unordered_map` that contains a string as a key and a vector as the key's associated value. Traditionally, this would be trivial. However, my program is trying to parse json data into this `unordered_map` data structure and there are no guarantees on the type of each vector being known in advance. The only thing that I can guarantee is that the type of each vector will be a one of the types in the following set of types: `string, int, double`. In order to try and achieve an unordered_map that functions this way, I've tried to use `variant`, but currently the variant implementation is leading to a timeout error. I'm hoping to get some advice on the cause of the timeout, and, ideally, how to resolve it.

The code is as follows (minimum example that replicates this issue):

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
// map stores col name as string and vector with col type
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::variant<double, long, std::string>>> mp;

   // input is type nlohmann::json
   json input = "{ \"happy\": \"yes\", \"pi\": 3.141, \"t\": 1608008400000 }"_json;

   for(auto& el : input.items()) { 
       if (mp.find(el.key()) == mp.end()) {
           std::cout << "trying insertion for key " << el.key() << std::endl;
           mp.insert({ el.key(), std::vector<std::variant<double, long, std::string>>{ el.value() } });
           std::cout << "inserted " << el.key() << " successfully!" << std::endl;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my input (note that my input is being passed to this program as type nlohmann::json):
`{"c":127.88,"h":127.9,"l":124.13,"n":867462,"o":124.34,"t":1608008400000,"v":157572262.0,"vw":126.5535},{"c":127.81,"h":128.37,"l":126.56,"n":550012,"o":127.41,"t":1608094800000,"v":95913591.0,"vw":127.5459}`

And here is the current output:

[image: And here is the current output]

```
inserted c successfully!
trying insertion for key h
inserted h successfully!
trying insertion for key l
inserted l successfully!
trying insertion for key n
inserted n successfully!
trying insertion for key o
inserted o successfully!
trying insertion for key t
[1]    40305 killed     ./test
```

I have tried to address a bunch of potential different issues regarding why this could be happening, but I have essentially confirmed via trial and error that the issue occurs when I try and use the `std::variant<std::string, long, double>` for my vector type. When I assign all of the vectors a uniform type (`double`, for example), all insertions work perfectly. However, the issue is one of extensibility. Even though this example only contains doubles and longs, in the future I'd ideally like to be able to parse some data that looks like this:
`{"a": "test", "b": 1243.343, "c": 120910394023332}` 
without error and have the return values be (with types shown for clarity):

`a : vector<string>{"test"}, b : vector<double>{1243.343}, c : vector<long>{120910394023332}`

If there's anything that I can clarify that would help answer this, please just let me know and I'll add it in.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and replace the shown code with a [mre], that anyone can cut/paste, ***exactly as shown*** then compile and run, and reproduce your problem themselves? See [ask] questions, in Stackoverflow's [help].

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Yes, absolutely! My apologies. Fixing it now!

Comment: why do you need a vector for map's values? In the examples provided, it's always just one element.

Comment: Hey Maxim, I realize now that my example initially provided may not be ideal. In the future, I hope to parse json that include both integers (longs, doubles) and strings. I'm trying to update the example now to reflect a better version of what I hope to accomplish.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've now updated the example with something that reflects the minimum working version of code that can reproduce this error (I believe!). Please note that you'll still need to install the nlohmann json package if you don't already have it. Can you let me know if there's anything else I should change.

Comment: You say there is a timeout, so it should be easy to get the debugger to tell you in what function all the time is going. If the program is stuck in the constructor of string for instance, that would be a nice hint.

Comment: Is there any good reason to transform **nlohmann** format to **your**?

Comment: @Phil1970 The best justification I can give is that the nlohmann format is unfamiliar and thus unwieldy for me right now. It might ultimately be worthwhile to keep everything in the nlohmann format, but since I don't know a whole lot about c++ and am just trying to practice working with different data structures, it's a worthwhile exercise (in my mind) to convert to and from nlohmann json.

Answer (score 2):

The following vector declaration:

```
std::vector<int> v{4};
```

This creates a vector default-initialized with 4 values. This overloaded `std::vector` constructor takes a single parameter that gives the initial size of the vector.

```
std::vector<std::variant<double, long, std::string>>{ el.value() } }
```

Keeping my introduction in mind, it should now be obvious that this is going to invoke the same constructor.

When I stepped through the above code in the debugger, my debugger revealed the fact that things quickly became unglued when 1608008400000 got passed into the constructor. The chances of my computer successfully creating a vector with one trillion, six hundred eight billion, eight million, and four hundred thousand values, of anything, are very, very slim.

`el.value()` does not return a variant. It returns a JSON value, and there's no ready-made mechanism for converting it to a variant. You have to do all the work yourself, something like:

```
   auto v=el.value();

   if (v.is_number())
   {
       if (v.is_number_float())
       {
           vv.emplace_back( (double)v);
       }
       else
       {
           vv.emplace_back( (long)v);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       vv.emplace_back( (std::string) v);
   }

   mp.insert({ el.key(), vv});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: `std::vector<int> v{4};` creates a vector default initialized with **1** value: 4. Your statement is incorrect. https://godbolt.org/z/a1Eoc6ezj

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to answer my own question (albeit in a roundabout way). I can check whether or not the type is integer with the `is_number_integer()` function in `nlohmann::json`. From there, if it is an integer, I can get the `uint64_t` value from it and then insert it into the variant vector. The only modification I had to make was to alter the variant vector to change the types available by removing `long` and adding `uint64_t`. Here's the new code:

```
int main() {
// map stores col name as string and vector with col type
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::variant<double, uint64_t, std::string>>> mp;

   // input is type nlohmann::json
   // input.push_back(json::object_t::value_type("t", 1608008400000));
   json input = "{ \"happy\": true, \"pi\": 3.141, \"t\": 1608008400000 }"_json;


   for(auto& el : input.items()) {
       if (mp.find(el.key()) == mp.end()) {
            std::cout << "trying insertion for key " << el.key() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "value is " << el.value() << " with type " << el.value().type_name() << std::endl;
            if (el.value().is_number_integer()) {
                mp.insert({ el.key(), std::vector<std::variant<double, uint64_t, std::string>>{ el.value().get<std::uint64_t>() } });
            }
            else {
                mp.insert({ el.key(), std::vector<std::variant<double, uint64_t, std::string>>{ el.value() } });
            }
            std::cout << "inserted " << el.key() << " successfully!" << std::endl;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```